# Android Application Screen Support for Phones and Tablets

Tags: android, manifest, tablet

I am quite new to Android Development. I am developing an application that should run on Android-based phones as well as on Android-based Tablets. My Question is that how to support multiple screens. I have developed a simple list-view application that I am testing on my Galaxy Tab but it is appearing quite smaller on the screen and not coming as a full-screen. I have tried making changes in the manifest file and declared minSdkVersion as 7.. Any advices or examples would be appreciated????

Answer (score 1):

The [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) section of the SDK docs should help you out. Have you looked at it?
Pay special attention to the Best Practices section and remember to use wrap_content, fill_parent, or the dp unit for layout dimensions in your views.